# Convert multidimesnional matrix to a one dimensional vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an MxN numpy matrix and would like to make it into a one dimensional vector that just stacks each row after another. Essentially something like this...

```
[x11, x12 ... x1m
 x21, x22 ... x2m
 .
 .
 xn1, xn2 ... xnm]
```

Goes to this...

```
[x11, x12 ... x1m, x21, x22 ... x2m ... xn1, xn2 ... xnm]
```

What is the best/ most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could you `.ravel`
From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]) 
>>> print np.ravel(x)
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also `.reshape()`, although this method demands that you know the destination shape (for at least all but one axis) of your output array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> foo = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> foo.reshape(1, 6)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

compare to:

```
>>> foo.reshape(-1, 1)
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6]])
```